# Two classes with conversion methods

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I have two matrix classes in C++ which inherit from the same base class `MatrixType`. They use different methods for storing sparse matrices, and are class templates because their entries may be of different types.

Each matrix type should have a method to allow to convert to the other type. The issue is that if I declare `toCRS` in the `MatrixCOO` class, the `MatricCRS` type for the argument is still undefined. How can I solve this problem?

```
class MatrixType { /*...*/ };

template<typename Scalar>
class MatrixCOO {
    // Private stuff...
public:
    // Public stuff...
    void toCRS(MatrixCRS & target) { // Issue is here: MatrixCRS is undefined
        // Fill target with elements from *this
    }
}


template<typename Scalar>
class MatrixCRS {
    // Private stuff...
public:
    // Public stuff...
    void toCOO(MatrixCOO & target) {
        // Fill target with elements from *this
    }
}
```

PS: in my understanding, even if I were to declare the class `MatrixCRS` before `MatrixCOO`, I would still be faced with the same problem in declaring `MatrixCRS::toCOO (MatrixCOO &)`.

Comment: declare now, define later.

Comment: Yes but even if I declare one class first, I still need to declare the method along with it...

Comment: @DreamsOfElectricSheep what would that imply in practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forward declare one, declare both, define function requiring both class definitions:

```
class MatrixType { /*...*/ };

template<typename Scalar> class MatrixCRS; // Forward declaration

template<typename Scalar>
class MatrixCOO {
    // Private stuff...
public:
    // Public stuff...
    void toCRS(MatrixCRS<Scalar>& target); // Just declare the method
};

template<typename Scalar>
class MatrixCRS {
    // Private stuff...
public:
    // Public stuff...
    void toCOO(MatrixCOO<Scalar>& target) {
        // ...
    }
};

// Implementation, we have both class definitions
template<typename Scalar>
void MatrixCOO<Scalar>::toCRS(MatrixCRS<Scalar> & target)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the lightning-fast response! I didn't know you could declare a class without also declaring all of its attributes.

Comment: *"declaring all of its attributes"* is the **definition** of the class.

Comment: Even if they are declared but not yet defined? Okay, thanks! I clearly had a little bit of a grey area there.

Comment: @Sean: yes. `class MatrixCRS;` is class _declaration_. `class MatrixCOO { void toCRS();` is class _definition_ and method _declaration_ both, then `MatrixCOO::toCRS(){}` is method _definition_.